# xslt(test1.xsl) does not go below root(of system-characteristics.xml)

Tags: xml, xslt

Subject: xslt(test1.xsl)  does not go below root(of system-characteristics.xml)

command line: 
java -jar SaxonHE9-7-0-1J\saxon9he.jar -o:oval-output.xml system-characteristics.xml -xsl:test1.xsl

Output:===== oval-output.xml =======

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  help (oval_system_characteristics)
```

========== system-characteristics.xml =============

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<oval_system_characteristics xmlns="http://oval.mitre.org/XMLSchema/oval-system-characteristics-5" xmlns:oval="http://oval.mitre.org/XMLSchema/oval-common-5" xmlns:oval-sc="http://oval.mitre.org/XMLSchema/oval-system-characteristics-5" xmlns:win-sc="http://oval.mitre.org/XMLSchema/oval-system-characteristics-5#windows" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://oval.mitre.org/XMLSchema/oval-system-characteristics-5 oval-system-characteristics-schema.xsd http://oval.mitre.org/XMLSchema/oval-common-5 oval-common-schema.xsd http://oval.mitre.org/XMLSchema/oval-system-characteristics-5#windows windows-system-characteristics-schema.xsd">

  <generator>
    <oval:product_name>cpe:/a:mitre:ovaldi:5.10.1.7</oval:product_name>
    <oval:product_version>5.10.1 Build: 7</oval:product_version>
    <oval:schema_version>5.10.1</oval:schema_version>
    <oval:timestamp>2016-01-16T19:34:09</oval:timestamp>
    <vendor xmlns="">The MITRE Corporation</vendor>
  </generator>
</oval_system_characteristics>
```

================== test1.xsl =======

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  xmlns:oval="http://oval.mitre.org/XMLSchema/oval-common-5" xmlns:oval-sc="http://oval.mitre.org/XMLSchema/oval-system-characteristics-5" xmlns:win-sc="http://oval.mitre.org/XMLSchema/oval-system-characteristics-5#windows" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://oval.mitre.org/XMLSchema/oval-system-characteristics-5 oval-system-characteristics-schema.xsd http://oval.mitre.org/XMLSchema/oval-common-5 oval-common-schema.xsd http://oval.mitre.org/XMLSchema/oval-system-characteristics-5#windows windows-system-characteristics-schema.xsd" version="2.0" >

<xsl:output method="xml"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:text>  help </xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>(</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="name(*)"/>
    <xsl:text>)</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="generator"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="generator">
    <xsl:text>  help </xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>(</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="name(*)"/>
    <xsl:text>)</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. While you added essential parts of your code, the question isn't straight forward. Read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for asking a better received question.

Answer (score 1):

Your first template matches the root, but the "root" is actually its own node one level above the first element in your document ( `oval_system_characteristics` ).

For the `xsl:apply-templates` to work within the template that matches `/`, it has to be able to find a template that matches a node within its current context.  Within the context of the root ( `/` ), the node that can be matched is the element `oval_system_characteristics`.  Since you've told the `xsl:apply-templates` to select only `generator`, and that element is not a child of the current context, you won't get a match.

It's better form to leave off the select attribute from the `xsl:apply-templates`, create a template for all the elements that you want to process all the way down the hierarchy of elements, and let XSL do the heavy lifting. The [built-in template rule](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#built-in-rule) will match an element and call `<xsl:apply-templates/>`, unless a more specific template matches.

So you would create another template that matches `oval_system_characteristics`, and if you don't want to do anything at that point, place only an `<xsl:apply-templates/>` within that template.

Since this template has matched on `oval_system_characteristics`, its `xsl:apply-templates` will try to find a match for the elements that are within its current context -- that is, it will find the template that matches generator (since generator is within the context of `oval_system_characteristic`).

You could also just change that `<xsl:apply-templates select="generator"/>` to `<xsl:apply-templates select="oval_system_characteristic/generator"/>`.  Since `oval_system_characteristic` is within the context of your template matching on `/`, the XPath path "`oval_system_characteristic/generator`" will point the XSLT processor to the template that matches "`generator`".  It's a useful shortcut -- but in general, using a plain `<xsl:apply-templates/>` is preferred because then the stylesheet can be written to accommodate any elements that might be contained within, say, `oval_system_characteristic`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your response. I made the changes. I am still studying your answers. By studying I mean I am re-reading "XLT Jumpstarter" chapter on namespaces to figure out how I misunderstood the section on namespace prefixes.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems that are preventing your stylesheet from producing the desired output.

1. The elements in your XML document are bound to a namespace. It may be difficult to see, because they are not using a namespace prefix, but `xmlns="http://oval.mitre.org/XMLSchema/oval-system-characteristics-5"` in the document element means that that element (and all of it's descendants, unless explicitly overridden) are bound to that namespace. In order to address it in an XPath in your XSLT, you should use the namespace-prefix declared in your stylesheet.
2. In the template for the root node, matching `/` (which is not the document element `oval_system_characteristics`, but a space above it in the tree of nodes), you are trying to select the child element generator. This may seem counter-intuitive, but that is how you could address a `comment()` or `processing-instruction()` that comes before the document element. In this template, the child of the root node is the document element `oval_system_characteristics`, so you need to adjust your XPath.
3. The template matching `generator` needs to match `oval-sc:generator`, because of the inherited namespace.
4. Inside of the template for `oval-sc:generator`, the context node is that generator element. To get it's name, use `name(.)` instead of `name(*)`. The latter would give you the name of the context node's child element. In this case, there are multiple elements so you would get an error because `name()` expects a single item.

If you adjust your stylesheet, it will produce the desired results:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  
    xmlns:oval="http://oval.mitre.org/XMLSchema/oval-common-5" 
    xmlns:oval-sc="http://oval.mitre.org/XMLSchema/oval-system-characteristics-5" 
    xmlns:win-sc="http://oval.mitre.org/XMLSchema/oval-system-characteristics-5#windows" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://oval.mitre.org/XMLSchema/oval-system-characteristics-5 oval-system-characteristics-schema.xsd http://oval.mitre.org/XMLSchema/oval-common-5 oval-common-schema.xsd http://oval.mitre.org/XMLSchema/oval-system-characteristics-5#windows windows-system-characteristics-schema.xsd" 
    version="2.0" >

    <xsl:output method="xml"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:text>  help </xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>(</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="name(*)"/>
        <xsl:text>)</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="oval-sc:oval_system_characteristics/oval-sc:generator"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="oval-sc:generator">
        <xsl:text>  help </xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>(</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="name(.)"/>
        <xsl:text>)</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```